# What are voicings in jazz and how are they different from chord inversions?

Tags: electric-guitar, jazz, chord-voicings

I've began studying jazz and I came across to something called "voicings","drop 2 voicings", etc. To me, voicings seem like chord inversions but from what I've found online it seems to be something more to them. Are they just shapes to play chords easier? How can I learn more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Voicings** are about *spacing* of the notes of a chord into different octaves and sometimes *doubling* some of them.
- **Inversions** are about what is the *lowest note*.

This example on Wikipedia has several different voicings for a C major chord. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voicing_%28music%29#Vertical_placement

If instead of C, say, E was the lowest note, then it would be the *first inversion* of C major.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(music)#Inverted_chords

**Voicings** are used to get slightly different **sounds and colors**. An open voicing has a more open, wide and clear sound, and usually you don't want voices too close to each other in low octaves, because of the muddy sound. Sometimes you might actually want a muddy sound. But sometimes you play a different voicing just to make a chord **easier to play** on the guitar, when a different voicing has an easier fingering. You might also use different voicings to get the **melody note** as the highest voice.

**Inversions** are used for their slightly different **harmonic functions**. For example, in the chord progression C/G - G7 - C, the chord C/G gives a strong hint that a dominant G7 is going to come soon. With C/G you feel like almost being at G7 already, just expecting the inevitable dominant to happen. But if you play it as C - G7 - C, there's no such hint, unless one comes from the rhythmic structure, say, being near the end of an 8-bar passage.

As far as I can see, the musical genre such as jazz doesn’t affect the meaning of the words in any way. Maybe in jazz, some effects are used more often.